# How to deploy precompiled JSF without .jsp to Tomcat6?

Tags: jsf, tomcat6, precompile

I'm trying to learn to deploy only precompiled JSF **without .jsp files** to Tomcat6, but hit HTTP Status 404 resource not found error. Below are the steps I did in my test (sorry, a bit lengthy):

The name of web application is *'precompile'*.

1. The original ***WAR*** containing 2 **JSF (.jsp) files** before precompilation is deployed and tested ok using this url:

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/precompile/faces/
   ```

   Navigating from index.jsp to the second page is also OK.
2. Precompile the deployed web application using the ant script described in [Tomcat 6 Jasper 2 Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Web_Application_Compilation), the command line is:

   ```
   ant -Dtomcat.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Dwebapp.path="%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\precompile"
   ```

   Build is successful. And the generated_web.xml is merged to `web.xml` automatically by adding the `addWebXmlMappings="true"` in jasper task. The web.xml is included at the lower part of this post.
3. With all the .jsp files still in the web application, test again in web browser - OK.
4. Stop tomcat. Delete the 2 .jsp files from the web application. Start tomcat. Test in web browser, getting to index.jsp is OK, but navigating to the second page hits a HTTP Status 404 requested resource is not available error:

   ```
   HTTP Status 404 - /modules/m1/pages/page1.jsp not found
   ```

   Not error shown in tomcat console.

The `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <filter>
  <filter-name>RichFacesFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>RichFacesFilter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
<!-- JSPC servlet mappings start -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.modules.m1.pages.page1_jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.modules.m1.pages.page1_jsp</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.modules.m1.pages.page1_jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/modules/m1/pages/page1.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<!-- JSPC servlet mappings end -->
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <display-name>precompile</display-name>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
 </login-config>
</web-app>
```

If need to refer to `faces-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config version="1.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee /web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">
 <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>indexBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.mypack.IndexBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
 <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>page1Bean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.mypack.Page1Bean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
 <navigation-rule>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>page1</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/modules/m1/pages/page1.jsp</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
 </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

I suspect it may be due to mistake in servlet mapping, but I'm not sure.

What did I do wrong? What's missing?

Thanks for reading this long question.

### Update 21 June 2011:

**Additional info**

If I access page1 with the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/precompile/faces/modules/m1/pages/page1.jsp
```

I will get a `Cannot find FacesContext` error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet org.apache.jsp.modules.m1.pages.page1_jsp threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext
at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.getFacesContext(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1855)
at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1672)
at org.apache.jsp.modules.m1.pages.page1_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(page1_jsp.java:94)
at org.apache.jsp.modules.m1.pages.page1_jsp._jspService(page1_jsp.java:70)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:427)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpAprProtocol.java:384)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Looks like the compiled file `page1_jsp` is having problem too.

What can be the cause? Has anyone done deploying precompiled JSF without .jsp successfully before? Mind to share how it's done?

Thank you.